# Error using rxjs - pipe and tap operators

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have following block of code which is expected to create a record on the DB.

```
createRole(role: RoleCreateModel): Observable<RoleCreateModel> {
    if (role) {
      return this.http
      .post<RoleCreateModel>(`${this.roleUrl}roles`, JSON.stringify(role), constants.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          tap(_ => this.apiHelper.notify('Role successfully created!', 'SUCCESS')),
          catchError(this.apiHelper.handleError('Method: createRole', 'FAIL'))
        );
    }
}
```

Above method is called by the following method:

```
const subscription: Subscription = this.rolesService.createRole(newRoleData).subscribe(res => {
     subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```

When an error occurs due to some business rule at the backend, HTTP status code 500 is returned which doesn't appear to be properly handled by the first method above.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:40)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:7)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:38)
    at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:56)
    at TapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at FilterSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at FilterSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:7)
```

What should be right approach to resolve this issue?

Comment: If your role is undefined you don't return an observable. Try to debug your () => createRole and check if you pass a valid role the first time you call this function.

Comment: `catchError()` accepts a function that needs to return an observable. So probably your `handleError()` doesn't return a function that would return an observable.

Comment: @martin You are right about the handleError function.

I'm unsure how it should be corrected. Any pointers?

`handleError(funcionName: string, method: string) {
    return function errorHandler(res: HttpErrorResponse) {
      this.logger.error(res);
      let eMsg: string = '';
      if (res.error.message) {
        eMsg = res.error.message;
      } else {
        eMsg = res.message || '';
      }
      const error = `Error in ${funcionName} ${eMsg ? ': ' + eMsg : ''}`;
      this.notify(error, 'FAIL');
    }.bind(this);
  }`

Comment: you can't unsubscribe inside subscription, if you want only one value use take(1) operator and dont use unsubscribe and subscription at all. also return something from the catch error, return empty() observable or of({}) and lastly i don't sure that the syntax in the tap operator is valid, try to replace it with ()  instead of the _

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleError` function must return an `Observable` of something. It can look like this for example:

```js
function handleError(funcionName: string, method: string) {
  return function errorHandler(res: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.logger.error(res);
    let eMsg: string = '';
    if (res.error.message) {
      eMsg = res.error.message;
    } else {
      eMsg = res.message || '';
    }
    const error = Error in ${funcionName} ${eMsg ? ': ' + eMsg : ''};
    this.notify(error, 'FAIL');
    return of(eMsg);
  }.bind(this);
}
```